# Drivers for freeduino (ATmega 328P)

Tags: arduino, driver

I am getting a lot of problem finding the drivers for Arduino Duemillanove- ATMega 328P .
I installed Silicon technologies- CP210X USB to UART Driver and FTDI drivers also but nothing happened. I chose the right port and board in arduino software . Still i am getting the error avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00. My pc is windows 7 32 bit operated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download driver from here
   http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/CP210x_VCP_Windows.zip
2. unplug the freeduino board and install driver software
   3.connect freeduino with PC

Answer (score -2):

go to  manage window from my computer , check whether port has been properly detected or not